# Make css adapt to screen size

Tags: css

I recently created a website for my bachelor thesis. I used percentages for the css part in order for the site to adapt on any screen size. However when i view the site from different screen sizes the various divs don't adapt well on the screen and the general layout of the page looks like a big mess. How can i address this problem in order to make it look the same on all the screen sizes? I can't link the site because it is on my Universities server and can only be accessed once you are connected to that network. Thanks.

Comment: it is not possible to advise anything specific without knowing how you have implemented this or that block and not knowing how it should work. The general solution in this case is to google css media queries

Comment: No one can do anything for you without code or a link to the issue. I also don't think it is possible to make the site look the same in mobile as it does on desktop in 90% of website designs. The sections or divs that are 50% on desktop can go 100% in mobile width media queries so the text/images inside are readable on smaller screens. If you stack your website sections in mobile, instead of trying to force the desktop layout to work, your mobile users will hate you less.
In our company we program the mobile layout first because it is often just a collapsed version of the desktop design.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'd recommend using media queries too, you can always try a quick fix using CSS3 `vh` and `vw`, you can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/).

Answer (score 0):

To make a website responsive you need to use media-queries you can't just use percents because height:width ratio is different on every device.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you did not make your website responsive. When you want to apply CSS styles depending on a device type (screen / print etc), you need to write media queries in your CSS file.

You should probably check the link below, it has media queries for all standard devices. 
[Media Queries](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)